# EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool while pip install on docker container

Tags: python, docker, airflow, pymssql

I just run docker-compose from https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow but as I need an extra python package, I tried to install it manually after running `docker exec -it <containerId> bash` but I have the following error:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aiXr.png)

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pymssql
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])"))': /packages/be/09/455835d22f84636dc646f4dc6afcc79c226d8bc253ef767ca8a922eec74a/pymssql-2.1.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])"))': /packages/be/09/455835d22f84636dc646f4dc6afcc79c226d8bc253ef767ca8a922eec74a/pymssql-2.1.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])"))': /packages/be/09/455835d22f84636dc646f4dc6afcc79c226d8bc253ef767ca8a922eec74a/pymssql-2.1.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])"))': /packages/be/09/455835d22f84636dc646f4dc6afcc79c226d8bc253ef767ca8a922eec74a/pymssql-2.1.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])"))': /packages/be/09/455835d22f84636dc646f4dc6afcc79c226d8bc253ef767ca8a922eec74a/pymssql-2.1.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/be/09/455835d22f84636dc646f4dc6afcc79c226d8bc253ef767ca8a922eec74a/pymssql-2.1.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

The days before I was able to run the `pip install pymssql` with no problems. No idea why could this happens right now, no changes were made to the docker-compose.yml file nor changes on the net

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on 16th August 2020. Noticed that https://files.pythonhosted.org SSL certificate was issued on 13th August. Then I logged into the container and checked the date and the date was 12th August. That's why SSL Verification was failing. If you are on windows then restart your docker desktop to sync time with host machine. But that would kill your running container. If you don't want to kill your running container then you have to manually update the time inside your docker container.